# Python -> Sorting List based on dependencies between elements

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, dependencies

I have a list of values as follows:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Next, I also have a dict of dependencies of the following format:

```
{1 : [2,3], 3: [4], 6: [7,8,9]}
```

This means that `2,3` must appear in the list before `1`, `4` must appear in the list before `3`, and `7`,`8`,`9` must all appear in the list before 6.

Therefore, a valid sorting would be:

```
[4,2,3,1,7,8,9,6]
```

Based on this example I have written code which is able to split the list into three subsets:

1. items which appear only on RHS (these should all be on top of the list) -> `7`,`8`,`9`,`4`,`2`
2. items which appear only on LHS (these can be placed on the bottom of the list) -> `1`,`6`
3. Items which appear both on the RHS and LHS ->`3`

I'm struggling with writing code to sort items which fall into the third category:

What would be a good way of sorting these items?

EDIT:

```
supersetR = set({})
supersetL = set({})
for dependency in dependencies: 
    supersetR = supersetR.union(dependencies[dependency])
    supersetL.add(dependency)

onlyL = supersetL - supersetR
onlyR = supersetR - supersetL 
LandR = supersetL.intersection(supersetR)
```

Comment: `Based on this example I have written code`. Can you add that code to the question

Comment: according to your logic, `d.values() + d.keys()` would be a valid sort (the values preceeding the keys)

Comment: I've added the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dict is actually a directed graph. What you want to get is called [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Python has an amazing library for graph processing - [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) - in which your problem can be solved with a pair of lines:

```
G = nx.DiGraph({1 : [2,3], 3: [4], 6: [7,8,9]})
list(reversed(list(nx.topological_sort(G))))
```

> `[2, 4, 3, 1, 8, 9, 7, 6]`

---

P.S. Note that your problem can be solved only with DAG cases, without any cycles. You can't order your list properly in the case of it. Just imagine a graph `1->2->3->1`. Whatever you will write to a list:

```
[1,2,3]
[2,3,1]
[3,1,2]
```

The first and the last nodes will be incorrect because in any case they have one node before it and one node after. You can check if your graph is a DAG with this function:

`nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(G)`

Comment: Your output doesn't respect his desired output no ? He wanted 7, 8 and 9 before 6

Comment: Sorry, I read his question wrongly. He just need a reversed topological order.

Comment: Is there an easy way of detecting cycles in these graphs?

Comment: I wrote it in my answer: `nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(G)`. If it returns True, there is no cycles. If False - they are.

Comment: But if you want to find cycles, not check that they are exist, you can use `cycles` submodule of networkx: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/cycles.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `networkx` library that implements topological sorting. But your problem seems to be the inverse of a topological sorting, so the code would look something like that :

```
import networkx
dict_sort = {1 : [2,3], 3: [4], 6: [7,8,9]}

graph = networkx.DiGraph(dict_sort)
list(reversed(list(networkx.topological_sort(graph))))
```

---

Output :

```
[2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 9, 6]
```

Comment: Topological sorting wouldn't work with circular dependencies right? I'd have to remove these?

Comment: Yes DAG mean directed __acyclic__ graph, it doesn't support circular dependencies

Comment: I added an explanation in my answer; Your problem can't be solved in the case of cyclic graphs. You have to remove cycles to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This [Rosetta Code example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort#Python) of topological sorting handles the case when dependencies may give multiple orderings that fit, by showing items whose sub-orderings still fit the dependencies.
For example: If 2 and 3 must appear before 1 and the items are `1, 2, 3, and 4` then the order of 2 with respect to 3 and 4 with respect to 1, 2, and 3 is variable.

The code also detects cycles, and has example runs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this sorting? Or just walking a graph?

```
tree = {1 : [2,3], 3: [4], 6: [7,8,9]}

# basic depth-first search of a graph
def dfs(tree, value, depth=0):
    if value in tree:
        for v in tree[value]:
            dfs(tree, v, depth+1)
    print(value, end=' ')

# find roots - nodes not listed as subs of any other node
roots = [v for v in tree if not any(v in vv for vv in tree.values())]

for r in roots:
    dfs(tree, r)
```

Gives:

```
2 4 3 1 7 8 9 6
```

Which appears to satisfy all of your constraints.